# Conditional probability of bijection of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I have been trying to proove the following with no success:

Suppose you have $X$ a discrete random variable over $A$, and $f:A \rightarrow B$ a **bijective** function.

It seems to me that if you define $Y:=f(X)$  then the conditional probability of $Y$ knowing $X=x$ should be either $1$ or $0$:

$$p(y|x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & y \neq f(x)\\
1 & y = f(x)
\end{cases}$$
$$x \in A, y \in B$$

I want to prove this formally, and don't know how to get started. It seems to me that the solution should follow from $X^{-1} x = Y^{-1} y$ --if $y = f(x)$-- but I do not know how to keep going from there.

Comment: You have to show that for every $x$ in the support of $X$ and every $y$ in the support of $f(X)$ that $$P(f(X) = y \mid X = x) = I(f(x) = y)$$ using the definition of conditional probability. f doesn't even have to be bijective for this to be true.

Comment: @Mason it seems to me that what you did there is just reformulate my question ?

Answer (score 1):

$$ \mathbb P(f(X) = y | X = x) = \frac{\mathbb P(f(X) = y ,  X = x)}{\mathbb P(X = x)} = \frac{\mathbb P(f(x) = y ,  X = x)}{\mathbb P(X = x)}  = \bigg\{ \begin{array}{cl} 1 & \text{if } f(x) = y \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.}   \end{array}$$
The event $\{ f(x) = y \} $ is either $\Omega$ or $\emptyset$.

Comment: That is not Bayes's formula. That is just definition of conditional probability. Also, the event "$\{f(x) = y\}$ is either $\Omega$ or $\emptyset$" is weird, did you mean $\{f(X) = y\} = \{X = f^{-1}(y)\} = \{X = x\}$ where $x$ the only value such that $f(x) = y$?

Comment: Fair enough, in France, we call it Bayes formula :). There is no typo, $f(x) = y$ is either true or false, so the set $\{ \omega \in \Omega: f(x) = y \} $ is either $\Omega$ or $\emptyset$.

Comment: +1,  @WilliamM. :  Note that this holds for any measurable function $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, not necessarily an injective or bijective function.  If the domain $A$ is finite or countably infinite then $f$ is automatically measurable. As another example, note that $\{\omega \in \Omega : 1+1=2\} = \Omega$ and $\{\omega \in \Omega : 1+1=3\} = \phi$.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers